# How can I create a dictionary that contains all the PHRED scores 0-93 encoded in fastq ASCII format?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Note that FASTQ files use the numbers 33-126 to represent phred qualities 0-93. This means that if you want to convert the numbers 0-93 into FASTQ format qualities you need to add 33 and convert to ASCII. I need to create a dictionary that contains all the PHRED scores 0-93 encoded in fastq ASCII format. The instructions are: The keys should be INTEGERS - not strings
and each value should be a string. I am new python, I have tried the code bellow however, not sure how to properly encoded it into a fastq ASCII format.

```
phred_scores = {}
keys = list(range(0,94))
values= list(range(33,127)
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for, comment below to let me know if this close:

```
phred={}
for x in range(0,94):
    phred.update({x : (chr(x+33).encode('ascii'))})
```

you can convert them back by using ord()

```
ord(b'!') -33  #--> 0
```

Looking at this: https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO-module.html

It looks like this is right, but theres more to fastq than just the numbers it seems. If you have a full line of you data, i could help more, but i think installing biopython might be the best help

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i am trying to make a dictionary, new to python and not sure how can do so while converting the numbers 0-93 into FASTQ format qualities ASCII format.

Comment: You got it correct. Hi @Lana, this is a good solution, it gives you a dictionary that maps phred scores to the letters in fastq.